# Python nested defaultdict with mix data types

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

So, how can I create a defaultdict for this:

```
{
    'branch': {
        'count': 23,
        'leaf': {
            'tag1': 30,
            'tag2': 10
        }
    },
}
```

so that, I'll get zeros for `count`, `tag1` and `tag2` as default? I wanna populate the dict dynamically while I'm reading the inputs. When I see a new `branch` I want to create a dict with `count` as zero and an empty dict as leaf. When I get a `leaf`, I want to create a key with it's name and set the value to zero.

**Update**:
Accepted Martijn's answer as it has more upvotes but other answers are equally good.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you would like to use a defaultdict for this, as opposed to a class? Something like
```class branch:
    def __init__(self, count=23, tag1=30, tag2=10):
        self.count, self.leaf = count, {'tag1': tag1, 'tag2': tag2}
```

Comment: @6c1, no. I just think that would be overkill for my simple use case and I wanted to give the `defaultdict` a shot. I'll revert back to class if that's not easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with `defaultdict`, because the factory doesn't have access to the key.

However, you *can* just subclass `dict` to create your own 'smart' `defaultdict`-like class. Provide your own [`__missing__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) that adds values based on the key:

```
class KeyBasedDefaultDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, default_factories, *args, **kw):
        self._default_factories = default_factories
        super(KeyBasedDefaultDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    def __missing__(self, key):
        factory = self._default_factories.get(key)
        if factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        new_value = factory()
        self[key] = new_value
        return new_value
```

Now you can supply your own mapping:

```
mapping = {'count': int, 'leaf': dict}
mapping['branch'] = lambda: KeyBasedDefaultDict(mapping)

tree = KeyBasedDefaultDict(mapping)
```

Demo:

```
>>> mapping = {'count': int, 'leaf': dict}
>>> mapping['branch'] = lambda: KeyBasedDefaultDict(mapping)
>>> tree = KeyBasedDefaultDict(mapping)
>>> tree['branch']['count'] += 23
>>> tree['branch']['leaf']['tag1'] = 30
>>> tree['branch']['leaf']['tag2'] = 10
>>> tree
{'branch': {'count': 23, 'leaf': {'tag1': 30, 'tag2': 10}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

An object has a `__dict__` that stores data, and allows you to programmatically set defaults. There's also an object called a `Counter` which I think you should use to delegate the counting of your leafs.

Thus, I recommend that you use an object with a collections.Counter:

```
import collections

class Branch(object):
    def __init__(self, leafs=(), count=0):
        self.leafs = collections.Counter(leafs)
        self.count = count
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Branch(leafs={0}, count={1})'.format(self.leafs, self.count)

BRANCHES = [Branch(['leaf1', 'leaf2']),
            Branch(['leaf3', 'leaf4', 'leaf3']),
            Branch(['leaf6', 'leaf7']),
           ]
```

And usage:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(BRANCHES)
[Branch(leafs=Counter({'leaf1': 1, 'leaf2': 1}), count=0),
 Branch(leafs=Counter({'leaf3': 2, 'leaf4': 1}), count=0),
 Branch(leafs=Counter({'leaf7': 1, 'leaf6': 1}), count=0)]
>>> first_branch = BRANCHES[0]
>>> first_branch.count += 23
>>> first_branch
Branch(leafs=Counter({'leaf1': 1, 'leaf2': 1}), count=23)
>>> first_branch.leafs['leaf that does not exist']
0
>>> first_branch.leafs.update(['new leaf'])
>>> first_branch
Branch(leafs=Counter({'new leaf': 1, 'leaf1': 1, 'leaf2': 1}), count=23)
```

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of Counter. I'll dig in.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question but I think this would also work:

```
def branch():
    return {
        'count': 0,
        'leaf': defaultdict(int)
    }

tree = defaultdict(branch)
tree['first_branch']['leaf']['cat2'] = 2
print json.dumps(tree, indent=2)

# {
#   "first_branch": {
#     "count": 0, 
#     "leaf": {
#       "cat2": 2
#     }
#   }
# }
```

Comment: I would go with what most elegantly solves/represents your problem. Real world? I think my answer does. But plus one for this creative solution.